# Image path not working in React as I tried to use use Image path inside an object which is also inside of an array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, responsive-design

I wanted to use image path inside an object as a value. This object is also inside of an array.
But the image is not showing up. Can anyone explain why?
My code:

```
const Data =[
    {
        imgsrc:"{require('../src/img/2.jpg')}",
        title:'this is me',
        sname:'Dark',
        link:'https://www.google.com'
    },
    {
        imgsrc:"{require('../src/img/1.jpg')}",
        title:'this is me',
        sname:'Dark',
        link:'https://www.google.com'
    }
];

export default Data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this are strings, not proper import statements ? Webpack or whatever tool you are using is unable to find this imports and interpret them correctly.

Try something like this:

```
const image1 = require('../src/img/1.jpg')
const image2 = require('../src/img/1.jpg')
const Data =[
    {
        imgsrc:image1,
            title:'this is me',
            sname:'Dark',
            link:'https://www.google.com'
    },
    {
        imgsrc:image2,
            title:'this is me',
            sname:'Dark',
            link:'https://www.google.com'
    }`enter code here`
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use require in the way you are proposing. Well, actually of course there is a way someone know how it can work, but I would highly recommend to not do it.

Consider this option:

```
const image2 = require('../src/img/2.jpg');

const Data =[
    {
        imgsrc:image2,
        title:'this is me',
        sname:'Dark',
        link:'https://www.google.com'
    },
];

export default Data;
```